# Code not looping through worksheets successfully

Tags: excel, vba, loops

This VBA 2007 code does the job but for only the first worksheet, it does not loop through the rest of the worksheets of the workbook (In where he is looking for a value and it gives back error where it's not on the first sheet but it should not). Can anyone advice me why¿? Thank you very much

```
Set sourcewb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=direccionArchivo)
 chakal = sourcewb.Index
               guapo = sourcewb.Worksheets.Count
                 For z = chakal To guapo
                    Set ws = Sheets(z)
                        sourcewb.Columns(1).Value =  Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(sourcewb.Columns(1))
                         Set gCell = ws.Columns("A").Find(what:=IDPEDIDO, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)

                            If Not gCell Is Nothing Then
                              'OTHER CODE NOT DISPLAYED
                            end if
                       Next z

                    Set gCell = Nothing
```

Comment: You do not get an error? sourcewb.columns(1) should give an error. A workbook has no columns. This must be ws.columns(1) in several places.

Comment: ok, maybe as this is in a for (inside an other for) it will work.

Comment: I also think that chakal should be 1. It is now set to the index of the workBOOK and that does not make sense if chakal is used for looping through the sheets: for z = 1 to sourcewb.worksheets.count.

Comment: See the code I have changed in the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this although it will still not work.

```
Set sourcewb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=direccionArchivo)
chakal = 1
guapo = sourcewb.Worksheets.Count
For z = chakal To guapo
   Set ws = sourcewb.Sheets(z)

   'This will not work, clean expects a string not a range (a column is a range)
   ws.Columns(1).Value =  Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(ws.Columns(1))


   Set gCell = ws.Columns("A").Find(what:=IDPEDIDO, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)

   If Not gCell Is Nothing Then
      'OTHER CODE NOT DISPLAYED
   end if
Next z
Set gCell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the clean function does not work on complete column. you have to loop through each cell in the column and use worksheetfunction.clean(cell.value). Secondly you have not used correct object model for worksheet which is workbook.worksheets.range. I have corrected your code and is as follows:

```
Sub t()
Dim sourcewb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set sourcewb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=direccionArchivo)
           guapo = sourcewb.Worksheets.Count
             For Z = 1 To guapo
                Set ws = sourcewb.Sheets(Z)
                    endrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                        For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(endrow, 1))
                            WorksheetFunction.Clean (cell)
                        Next cell
                     Set gCell = ws.Columns("A").Find(what:=IDPEDIDO, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)

                        If Not gCell Is Nothing Then
                          'OTHER CODE NOT DISPLAYED
                        End If
                   Next Z

                Set gCell = Nothing
End Sub
```